# Swift / SnappingSlider / two instances of the slider

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the [SnappingSlider](https://github.com/rehatkathuria/SnappingSlider).
I want to use two instances of the Slider and be able to change different values depending on the used Slider.

This is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import SnappingSlider

class ViewController: UIViewController, SnappingSliderDelegate {

private var remainingTime:Double = 0
private let remainingTimeLabel:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
private let remainingTimeSlider:SnappingSlider = SnappingSlider(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0), title: "Slide Me")
private let percentageSlider:SnappingSlider = SnappingSlider(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0), title: "Slide Me")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    remainingTimeLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, 80.0)
    remainingTimeLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.21 - remainingTimeLabel.bounds.size.height * 0.75)
    remainingTimeLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TrebuchetMS-Bold", size: 25.0)
    remainingTimeLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    remainingTimeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    remainingTimeLabel.text = "\(remainingTime)"
    self.view.addSubview(remainingTimeLabel)

    remainingTimeSlider.delegate = self
    remainingTimeSlider.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.9, 50.0)
    remainingTimeSlider.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.2)
    self.view.addSubview(remainingTimeSlider)

    percentageSlider.delegate = self
    percentageSlider.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.9, 50.0)
    percentageSlider.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.4)
    self.view.addSubview(percentageSlider)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func snappingSliderDidIncrementValue(slider: SnappingSlider) {

    remainingTime += 0.5
    remainingTimeLabel.text = "\(remainingTime)"
}

func snappingSliderDidDecrementValue(slider: SnappingSlider) {

    remainingTime = max(0, remainingTime - 0.5)
    remainingTimeLabel.text = "\(remainingTime)"
}


}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
func snappingSliderDidIncrementValue(slider: SnappingSlider) {

if slider == sliderA {
    remainingTime += 0.5
    remainingTimeLabel.text = "\(remainingTime)"
} else if slider == sliderB {
    integerXY = += 0.5
    labelXY.text = "\(remainingTime)"
}
```

I have send the author of the Slider an email and got the follwing text back: You can set a single object to act as a delegate for multiple instances of the slider. So, you’d set the .delegate property of the sliders to be whatever object you have conforming to the delegate and then you’d do the check inside of the delegate callbacks exactly how you’ve shown underneath.

But I don't get it... Help is very appreciated.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Your code looks basically correct.  You need to substitute the correct names for your sliders and labels though.

Comment: @vacawama see edit, please... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
func snappingSliderDidIncrementValue(slider: SnappingSlider) {
    if slider == remainingTimeSlider {
        remainingTime += 0.5
        remainingTimeLabel.text = "\(remainingTime)"
    }
    else if slider == percentageSlider {
        // do something for this slider
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  Enjoy Seattle, WA.  I used to live in WA (which is the WA in my name VA-CA-WA-MA).

Comment: thank you. i will :) thank you for your help again... got stuck on this a while